# Cannot run Kivy 1.9.0 with Anaconda

Tags: python, kivy

I tried to get Anaconda working with Kivy 1.9.0 following the guidelines here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Connecting-Kivy-with-Anaconda-(OSX)

When I try to run kivyconda with a sample kivy program, I get:

```
Tabishs-MBP:Desktop tabchas$ kivyconda test.py 
discarding /Users/tabchas/anaconda2/bin from PATH
prepending /Users/tabchas/anaconda2/envs/kivy/bin to PATH
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-   11-14_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil,     img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
sdl2 - ImportError:     dlopen(/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.so, 2): Library     not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
Referenced from: /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.so
Reason: image not found
File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File"/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Was anyone successful in getting Kivy 1.9.0 to work with Anaconda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these instructions to install Kivy 1.9 in Anaconda 2.4:

http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html

You will also need pygame and need to follow instructions on their website for OS X.